# Are azure web jobs appropriate to import large amounts of data

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am working on an application where we receive csv files from a govt. dept. that has approx 1.5 million rows, monthly. We have to get this into azure table storage. We are trying to avoid having to provision VM's for this and are wondering if webjobs are a good choice for such a large dataset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they should work. WebJobs are nothing more that a process running on the website machine.

You'll probably want to turn on the "Always On" feature if your webjob will take a long time to complete.